# Preventing spoofing attack - how to ensure my client receives orders from the real server?

Tags: security, authentication, server, restful-authentication, spoofing

I'm working on a Chrome extension that integrates with a website. My users can do actions on this website when they are logged in to it.

I have a Socket.IO server that delivers commands to my Chrome extension. Once a command arrived, the extension invokes a local function from the host website. Then, the host website, which has an authenticated active session with its own API, will invoke some update/insert call.

[image: Normal flow]

I recently realized a potential security issue, which is - if anyone spoofs my server address on my extension clients organization, he can easily abuse it to send his own parameters on behalf of my server ([image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UguG.png)).

Is there any smart way to ensure my client communicates with the real server and not an imposter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTPS secured connection.

> This is one of the features of HTTPS (SSL/TLS) - it can prevent a MITM
> attack and prevent the destination server from being impersonated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586398/12595469